# Font-face does not work on firefox. Works well on others

Tags: css, firefox, webfonts

I have a project that's been using font-face without problem for some time.
Today I checked and font face is not working on firefox v14 and v15 provably also not working on v12+ as is the case in this thread: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/17337/font-face-problem-with-firefox-v-12/p1
My problem is exactly the same as in the previous thread.

To summarize.
I'm using font face to load web fonts like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdCnBold';
    src: url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.svg#TradeGothicLTStdCnBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

and then

```
#bea .bea {
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdCnBold';
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

The fonts are loading correctly according to firebug.
It works on safari, chrome, IE and **some firefoxs**.
I've tried 6 firefoxs (v13-15) and it worked in some of them and not on others. I haven't been able to establish any reason why.

I've also looked for the firefox configuration value 
    gfx.font_rendering.cleartype.always_use_for_content;
And i've noticed is set to false in all the firefoxs I tested, even the ones that work correctly.

Live example:
http://comoquierascolacao.com/jovenestalentos/

How it should look:
http://postimage.org/image/n2r9fxdsv/[image: how it should look]

To summarize:
- The routes work.
- The routes are in the same domain, no cross-domain issues.
- It does work in some firefoxs and it doesn't in others (no reason that i can figure out).
- It did work in my own firefox before, maybe prior to v12.

Thank you all, any help will be greatly appreciated because this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Have you tried Google Web Fonts ? They provide a better cross-browser support . Maybe you can be inspired from their source code.

Comment: Yes I did. Unfortunatelly my client wants THAT font and not another. I use google web fonts whenever they let me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my fault.
It was a crossdomain problem after all.
The fonts where loaded from `www.domain...`even when accessing `http://domain...`
Reddirecting everyone to www.domain should solve the problem and I think will be a good practice from now on.
Another solution would be to load the fonts with relative routes.

Comment: Having similar problems using relative routes in FF122.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem about FF doesnt show font-face properly.
Here is the workaround for who may have this problem:

Try declare "eot" fonts at the end of the block. Like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdCnBold';
src: url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.svg#TradeGothicLTStdCnBold') format('svg');
src: url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.eot');
src: url('/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Comment: Had the same problem using only .ttf and .otf fonts; changed the order (.otf) first and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript console (Herramientas-> Desarrollador web-> Consola de errores) displays several errors:

```
Fecha y hora: 13/09/2012 9:41:37
Advertencia: downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "TradeGothicLTStdCnBold" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:4)
source: (end of source list)
Archivo de origen: http://www.comoquierascolacao.com/jovenestalentos//style/style.css?v=1
Línea: 0
Código fuente:
@font-face {   font-family: "TradeGothicLTStdCnBold";   font-style: normal;   font-weight: normal;   src: url("/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/jovenestalentos/fonts/tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.svg#TradeGothicLTStdCnBold") format("svg"); }
```

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. I didn't reproduce your error in my console (believe me, is the first thing I look) but seeing that I was loading inorrectly the styles (..jovenestalentos//style...).
That made me look the url's more closely.
www.comoquierasc... works and
http://www.comoquierasc...  doesn't.
It was a crossdomain issue after all.
Sorry!
and thanks all.

Comment: In case you where checking Firebug's console, I've learnt that it doesn't always show all error messages. Built-in console is more reliable.

Comment: This error have only showed up after I was playing around with the type of errors reported in the firefox inspector's console. It didn't show by default.

Answer (score 1):

my solution: on domain with www. work everything fine, but without www. FF problem apeared.
so I use redirection to www. in .httaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and it works! Thanks Hanoc